# How can I check if package is installed in the project

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm creating a module that looks for a text field in scene.
if TextMeshPro is installed it looks for it, and if not, look for regular textfield/text mesh

the question is: how can I condition (pseudo code)

```
if(textMeshProExists)
    Look for A
else
    Look for B
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [Package Manager scripting API](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-api.html) to interact with the Package Manager programmatically.

**Browsing the list of packages in a Project:**

```
using System;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.PackageManager.Requests;
using UnityEditor.PackageManager;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Unity.Editor.Example {
   static class ListPackageExample
   {
       static ListRequest Request;

       [MenuItem("Window/List Package Example")]
       static void List()
       {
           Request = Client.List();    // List packages installed for the Project
           EditorApplication.update += Progress;
       }

       static void Progress()
       {
           if (Request.IsCompleted)
           {
               if (Request.Status == StatusCode.Success)
                   foreach (var package in Request.Result)
                       Debug.Log("Package name: " + package.name);
               else if (Request.Status >= StatusCode.Failure)
                   Debug.Log(Request.Error.message);

               EditorApplication.update -= Progress;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: what about `#if PackageName` above the header?

Comment: @likuku They added Version Defines in Assembly definition files. Check that out!

Answer (score 1):

a asmdef file can help this.

[image: asmdef]

Add one Version Defines, PACKAGE_ADDRESSABLES.

you can use it in your code.

[image]

Comment: thank you mate.
It could suit my needs but just almost.
the code I need moves from 1 project to another and may be used for different packages on diferent projects. some with the package installed and some without.

That is, assing ASMDEF to each project may be longer than modifying the script.
that's why i was asking for a programatic code.